# I found something strange with Autocomplete as search functionality isn't working as expected (Or maybe I'm wrong)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've implemented a basic search functionality using freeSolo material-ui, but I have a trouble when my array has two same titles. When I attempt to type 'a' I strangely get Woolies as one of the option. When you click elsewhere within the application and click on search box again, I get the correct output.

Confused how can I get rid of this bug.

1. Screenshot 1
   [image: Screenshot]
2. Screenshot 2
   [image]

REPO URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ovvfuz?file=demo.tsx

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Option in autocomplete should have a unique key. Try to figure out the answer with adding the render option to the Autocomplete.

Comment: Thanks mate. Your tip worked. 

renderOption={(props, option) => {
    return (
      <li {...props} key={option.id}>
        {option.name}
      </li>
    );
  }}